# power apps, how to get field value from parent to child table and roll up these values for other parent value

Tags: powerapps, rollup, model-driven

power apps, how to get field value from parent to child table and roll up these values for other parent value

example
I have master worker list with wages,

I also have task list as a parent with chiled table of assigned workers,
relationship one to many
I need to get wages from workers and roll it up in task sheet

I tried to used calculated field to get the value from parent,
But roll up can't work with calculated field